# Manipulate a local static pointer variable outside the function where it is defined

Tags: c++, function, variables, pointers, static

I want to visit and modify a static variable defined in a function in global scope, but the 2nd and the 3rd lines of output are unexpected, why ox is 0?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int * foo(){
    static int *x = new int(5);
    cout << *x << '\t' << &x << endl;
    *x++;
    return x;
}

int main(){
    int * ox;
    ox = foo();
    cout << *ox << '\t' << &ox << endl;
    *ox++;
    cout << *ox << '\t' << &ox << endl;
    int * t= foo();
}
```

The output is (on my machine):

```
5   0x6021d0
0   0x7fffdc82d3a0
0   0x7fffdc82d3a0
0   0x6021d0
```

Any comment is welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got caught by some parsing issues.  Let's look at the code line-by-line:

```
static int * x = new int(5);
```

The first time control flow passes over this line, `x` is assigned a pointer to a newly allocated `int` initialized with the value 5.  Each following time control flow passes by, the line will be “skipped”.  No surprises so far.

```
cout << *x << '\t' << &x << endl;
```

I suspect you've meant to print the address of the value, not the pointer, hence typed

```
cout << *x << '\t' << x << endl;
```

Now it becomes interesting.  This line probably doesn't do what you think it does.

```
*x++;
```

The compiler parses this as `*(x++)`.  What is happening is that the pointer `x` is advanced and its previous value dereferenced and that result thrown away.  (Which invokes undefined behavior the next time the function is entered because now `x` points one past the allocated memory location.)  You've probably assumed that it be parsed as `(*x)++` which would increment the value pointed-to by x.

The same pattern applies to your `main`.

If I compile your original code with GCC and pass the `-Wall` flag (which is always a good idea), it gives us a good hint to what is going on:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int* foo()’:
main.cpp:8:7: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
   *x++;
       ^

main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:16:8: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
   *ox++;
        ^
```

Comment: @5gin12eder No, `*x++` uses the temporary from the postfix operator when dereferencing, it doesn't dereference the already incremented pointer. Indeed, it is parsed as `*(x++)`, but the result of `(x++)` is a temporary equal to the "old" `x`.

Comment: @vsoftco Oh, you are right.  Overlooked that.  The undefined behavior comes the next time the pointer is dereferenced.

Comment: Nice find spotting the `&x`.

Answer (score 4):

Order of operations.  Twice, you perform `*ox++;`.

This is **not** evaluated as `(*ox)++` *"increment the pointed-to value"*.

It is `*(ox++)` *"increment the pointer"*.

> why ox is 0?

`ox` is pointing to `0` coincidentally.  You have incremented it to point to memory that you do not own.

Comment: Thank you! I am so careless : )

Comment: @Myzh you're welcome!  Take a look at 5gon12eder's answer too - they noticed before I did that you're also printing "address of the pointer"... +1 to that.  :)